# Error: Unterminated String Literal

Tags: javascript

First off, I am NOT a web developer; I'm not building websites; I just want to surf the internet in peace. However, today I've started receiving this error over and over again on every website I go to. How do I make it stop? I'm using firefox...please help before I have to reformat!

Comment: My guess is that you have a firefox add-on that is causing a problem.  I'd suggest disabling all your add-ons to see if the issue goes away.  If so, you can narrow down which one is causing the issue.  If not, then try another browser and see if you get the error there.

Comment: Holy crap, why didn't I think of that? Thank you so much, I had an add on called 'ads no more' and that is exactly what was causing the problem! Again, thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turning my comment into an answer:

My guess is that you have a firefox add-on that is causing a problem. I'd suggest disabling all your add-ons to see if the issue goes away. If so, you can narrow down which one is causing the issue. If not, then try another browser and see if you get the error there.